# SSL on Service Stack

Tags: c#, mono, servicestack

Is SSL supported on Service Stack on Mono?

I only have access to a mac and the instructions I found here ask you to use a windows tool to create a pvk file:
http://joshua.perina.com/geo/post/using-ssl-https-with-mono-httplistener

The site is hosted as a linux daemon process using an upstart script to keep the server up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up writing some code in my app host to enable SSL support for Service Stack, which uses HttpListener under the covers. Here is some code that will enable SSL for Service Stack for a console application:

```
public class AppHost : AppHostHttpListenerBase
{
    public AppHost() : base("Service", typeof(AppHost).Assembly) 
    {
    }

    public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
    {
        Plugins.Add(new RazorFormat());
    }

    static void AddP12 (string filename, string password, ushort port)
    {
        string dirname = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        string path = Path.Combine(dirname, ".mono");
        path = Path.Combine(path, "httplistener");
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Creating directory: " + path);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }
        X509Certificate2 x509 = null;
        try {
            x509 = new X509Certificate2 (filename, password);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.Error.WriteLine ("error loading certificate [{0}]", e.Message);
            return;
        }

        string target_cert = Path.Combine (path, String.Format ("{0}.cer", port));
        if (File.Exists(target_cert)) 
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine ("error: there is already a certificate for that port.");
            return;
        }
        string target_pvk = Path.Combine (path, String.Format ("{0}.pvk", port));
        if (File.Exists(target_pvk)) {
            Console.Error.WriteLine ("error: there is already a certificate for that port.");
            return;
        }

        using (Stream cer = File.OpenWrite (target_cert)) 
        {
            byte[] raw = x509.RawData;
            cer.Write (raw, 0, raw.Length);
        }

        PrivateKey pvk = new PrivateKey();
        pvk.RSA = x509.PrivateKey as RSA;
        pvk.Save(target_pvk);           
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string listeningOn = string.Empty;
        if (args.Length == 1)
            listeningOn = "http://*:" + args[0] + "/";
        else if (args.Length == 3)
        {
            listeningOn = "https://*:" + args[0] + "/";
            AddP12(args[1], args[2], Convert.ToUInt16(args[0]));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Usage: [port] [p12 certificate] [p12 password]");
            return;
        }
        AppHost appHost = new AppHost();
        appHost.Init();
        appHost.Start(listeningOn);
        Console.WriteLine("Service Stack Server started at {0}, listening on {1}", DateTime.Now, listeningOn);
        while (true) System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like it just copies a cert from one location to another. How does that help? Presumably certificate configuration in the operating system is also required?