# HttpListener (ServiceStack) using SSL without configuration

Tags: ssl, servicestack, httplistener

In looking to provide a self-hosted `ServiceStack` backend to a single-page app, I want to require SSL.

I've seen the answers related to configuring the server with the certificate using `httpcfg/netsh`, but I'd like to not have that configuration step if possible.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459918/ssl-on-service-stack), but it doesn't compile.

The `PrivateKey` class is missing.  Of course, I'm assuming `PrivateKey.Save(...)` does something similar to what `httpcfg/netsh` does during the manual configuration.  My question is, is this 'no configuration' approach with `SSL` on `HttpListener` possible?  Is that previously linked answer even possible?  If so, where does `PrivateKey` come from?

Comment: Well, as so often happens, I made progress after having resorted to asking a question.  The PrivateKey class is a Mono [class](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/effa4c07ba850bedbe1ff54b2a5df281c058ebcb/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Authenticode/PrivateKey.cs) and comes from Mono.Security.Authenticode.  It's not doing anything special other than handling that pvk format.  I found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13379963/httplistener-with-https-on-monotouch/13385734#13385734) which lead me to the source I couldn't find before.